# sftp connection refused issue

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am just trying to connect with my sftp server it gives me error like

```
ssh: connect to host 192.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

i am using below command to connect from my mint(linux) os

ssh 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Filezilla or DS-5 (sftp) refused to connect to my embedded linux (sunxi 3.4.103) system, however teraterm (ssh) worked ok. I commented out the line(s) in .bashrc (also look at .profile) which was causing interactive data to be sent back to the non-interactive client, and it fixed the problem. Apparently this is a longstanding problem as documented in section 2.9 of http://www.openssh.com/faq.html.

Comment: You don't say the line, and the link given is broken.

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that the machine you are attempting to connect to has an SSH server installed.

On the host (the machine your connecting to):

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep ssh
```

Make sure that the output includes an SSH server. The most common one will show

```
openssh-server                  install
```

This is the server I will show you how to use. If you do not have an SSH server installed, install it with the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Once you are sure that an SSH server is installed, attempt to connect to it from itself first:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1
```

Type "yes" to add it's fingerprint to the known hosts and then enter your password.

If that works, try to connect from your client machine (the machine you are connecting from).

If it still doesn't work, you may need to unblock port 22 on the host machine's firewall. To do so, type:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems like SSH(port 22) is not enabled for your target machine. What is the OS of your target machine ?

Comment: I think it is linux os